# GRANT SELECT TO role (without specifying ON object)

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-grant

What is the result of an instruction like the following on SQL Server 2008+?

```
GRANT SELECT TO role
```

(without specifying ON object!)

```
The 'Command(s) completed successfully.'
```

My tests have concluded that the role will have `SELECT` permission on `ALL` past and future objects - `TABLES, VIEWS,` etc.

Is this true?

Comment: Yes, that is the way it works. `GRANT EXECUTE TO role` does the same thing for execute permissions on stored procedures - existing and future ones.

Comment: If you don't specify an object, it sets it at the database level. So it is equivalent to any object capable of having select granted to it in that database being granted to that role.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming.